Nested Data List
I have (many) assignments dates, for each date it has many assignments names, for each name it has its own time, for each time(assignment)  it has many business activities, for each activity it has many operation sites. (Mind Map of the business has been attached below)
The user sould be able to reassign and delete the whole date (bulk of assignmets) or signle(or more) assignment
What is the best practice to represent this?
Here's a quick map of the business:

My solution:


You can likely approach this solution as follows:

Given the IA's complexity within each date, letting the user traverse one day at a time is preferable. This accommodates progressive disclosure of information and eases the cognitive load on the user.

Sounds good. But the problem here is you didn't let the user reassign a bulk of dates at once to another workforce member which is the main goal of our business here

You should do that at a higher level than this. This page is technically trying to achieve too much at the same time which might be overwhelming to say the least. You can acheve your said goal by creating a calendar view that allows the user to select days and bulk assign them.
